# why the function didn't return data in component although it appear on console correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to show books that user had added them before and this will happen when the user clicks button but I didn't get a result, what is the problem?

//here is the function

```
  displayBooks = () => {

    const { users, books } = this.state
    const user = users.find(user => user.email === currentUser.email)
    const arrayHaveFavBooksId = user.favBooks
    let arrayHaveObjOfuserFavBooks = [];

    for (let book of books) {
      for (let bookId of arrayHaveFavBooksId)
        if (bookId === book.id) {
          arrayHaveObjOfuserFavBooks.push(book)
        }
    }
// 
 console.log(arrayHaveObjOfuserFavBooks);

    const showBooks = arrayHaveObjOfuserFavBooks.map((book, id) => {
      return (
          <figure key={id}>
            <img src={book.photoURL} alt={book.title} />
          </figure>
      )
    })
    return showBooks
  }
```

here is the render on component

```
 render() {
    return (
      <section className="profile">
            <button onClick={this.displayBooks}> show my Books</button>
      </section>
    );
  }
```

// here is imgfor logging [image: data appear withoud proplem in console]

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong here, but also don't see you console.logging anything.

Comment: Hi climber, how are you using this `displayBooks` function in your render function?

Comment: thanks, I edit the Question so could you see and tell me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing the `onClick` callback with the rendering phase from the Component.  You're not supposed to return itens inside the `onClick` callback, but rather trigger a re-render by calling `setState` (or other re-rendering operation e.g. update on Redux).

One way to solve this would be to create a flag on the component state and update it from the `onClick` callback. like so:

```
class Comp extends React.Component {
  state = {
    books: ...,
    users: ...,
    booksVisible: false,
  }
 
  // displayBooks implementation here

  toggleVisibility = () => {
    const { booksVisible } = this.state
    // Toggles it so you can open and close
    this.setState({ booksVisible: !booksVisible })
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <section className="profile">
            <button onClick={this.toggleVisibility}> Show my books</button>
            { booksVisible ? this.displayBooks() : null }
      </section>
    );
  }
}
```

In this way, the `onClick` callback manages only the state of the component, while the rendering is entirely made inside of the `render` function.